# CakePHP problems by not getting the _schema

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHP problems by not getting the _schema

my model in cakephp:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Product Model
 *
 * @property Image $Image
 * @property Client $Client
 */
class Product extends AppModel {
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'title';


}
?>
```

My controller in cakephp:

```
$this->Product->recursive = -1;
var_dump($this->Product->_schema);
```

var_dump gives me null

I do the same with another table in BBDD and get results.

Results another table in BBDD:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [type] => integer
            [null] => 
            [default] => 
            [length] => 11
            [key] => primary
            [collate] => 
            [comment] => 
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [type] => integer
            [null] => 
            [default] => 
            [length] => 11
            [collate] => 
            [comment] => 
        )

    [title] => Array
        (
            [type] => string
            [null] => 
            [default] => 
            [length] => 255
            [collate] => utf8_general_ci
            [comment] => 
            [charset] => utf8
        )

    [description] => Array
        (
            [type] => text
            [null] => 
            [default] => 
            [length] => 
            [collate] => utf8_general_ci
            [comment] => 
            [charset] => utf8
        )

    [date] => Array
        (
            [type] => date
            [null] => 
            [default] => 
            [length] => 
            [collate] => 
            [comment] => 
        )

    [urlvideo] => Array
        (
            [type] => string
            [null] => 
            [default] => 
            [length] => 255
            [collate] => utf8_general_ci
            [comment] => 
            [charset] => utf8
        )

    [image] => Array
        (
            [type] => string
            [null] => 
            [default] => 
            [length] => 255
            [collate] => utf8_general_ci
            [comment] => 
            [charset] => utf8
        )

    [created] => Array
        (
            [type] => datetime
            [null] => 
            [default] => 
            [length] => 
            [collate] => 
            [comment] => 
        )

    [modified] => Array
        (
            [type] => datetime
            [null] => 
            [default] => 
            [length] => 
            [collate] => 
            [comment] => 
        )

)
```

thanks

PD:

my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `characteristics` text,
  `urlvideo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pdf` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: Which version of Cake do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

->_schema stores a cached copy of the schema of a model. If you haven't run any queries on the model, it will be empty.

Try calling:

```
$this->Model->schema()
```

(which fetches the schema, caches it in Model->_schema, and then returns the data)

Comment: I tried that. It failed with `Fatal error: Call to a member function schema() on a non-object`

Comment: Are you sure you're replacing `Model` with the name of your model? e.g. `$this->Product->schema()`

Comment: I'm on v2.6 and when I try this from the beforeFilter of the controller I get: `Indirect modification of overloaded property Model::$_schema has no effect ` Any ideas?